# Is there a way to get PiP enable status in Settings on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, picture-in-picture

After I manually turn off PiP in **Settings->General->Picture in Picture**, I can still get ***true*** when calling *AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported()* as well as *AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPicturePossible*. Is it possible to know if the user has turned it off from Settings?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

You can enable/disable it specifically for your app by setting `canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline` on `AVPictureInPictureController`.

---

And here is a little bit more info about `isPictureInPictureSupported()` and  `isPictureInPicturePossible` from the official [docs](https://Before%20presenting%20a%20user%20interface%20to%20start%20Picture%20in%20Picture,%20call%20the%20isPictureInPictureSupported()%20method%20to%20determine%20if%20the%20current%20device%20supports%20the%20feature,%20and%20check%20the%20isPictureInPicturePossible%20property%20value%20to%20determine%20whether%20PiP%20is%20possible%20in%20the%20current%20context.).

> Before presenting a user interface to start Picture in Picture, call the isPictureInPictureSupported() method to determine if the current device supports the feature and check the isPictureInPicturePossible property value to determine whether PiP is possible in the current context.

Comment: Why is it "unfortunate"?

Comment: The person wants to retrieve that info (for whatever reason) but can't. Doesn't it make it "unfortunate"?

Comment: However, even though I set canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline to true, PiP is still disabled if I turn it off from Settings. Tested it on iPhone Xs, iOS 14.7

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behavior. This property only works if the user has enabled it from the Settings